# How can I verify the state of a WPF checkbox during a UI Automation Unit Test using the Windows Application Driver?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ui-automation, winappdriver

My simple WPF application includes a check box. I am trying to test this application automatically with the Windwos Application Driver.
After creating a session the check box is clicked. Afterwards I want to verify if the checkbox is checked. But the type of the check box object is WindowsElement so my code can not work.

In other words: How do I get access to these control types in a WinAppDriver test?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controltypesoverview

```xml
<CheckBox AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CheckBox1"/>
```

```cs
[Test Method]
public void TestMethod1()
{
            const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
            const string SimpleWPFTestID = @"C:\Users\bla\source\repos\SimpleWPFApp\SimpleWPFApp\bin\Debug\SimpleWPFApp.exe";

            DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", SimpleWPFTestID);

            var session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);

            WindowsElement CheckBox1 = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CheckBox1");
            CheckBox1.Click();
            Assert.IsTrue(CheckBox1.IsChecked); // this line does not work :-(
}
```

Comment: Does validation on `CheckBox1.IsChecked` work?

Comment: No, that is exactly the part of the line that fails.

Comment: Please try this `session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CheckBox1").Click(); Assert.IsTrue(CheckBox1.Checked);` or `session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CheckBox1").IsChecked = true; Assert.IsTrue(CheckBox1.IsChecked);`

Comment: I more meant: to try `IsChecked` instead of `Checked`. I believe `Checked` is an Event not a property

Comment: You are right: I should have written 'IsChecked'. But this does not solve my problem. Error:
"'WindowsElement' does not contain a definition for 'IsChecked' and no accessible extension method 'IsChecked' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Also
`session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CheckBox1").IsChecked = true;`
does not work (for the same reason).

Comment: Your problem seems to be similar to [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/198) on github.
[The solution](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Tests/UWPControls/CheckBox.cs) is linked in the answer from timotiusmargo.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much, PixelPlex! [That](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/198) is the answer. I also had a look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/236) answer. Now it works :-)

```
Assert.IsTrue(CheckBox1.Selected);
```